# facing issue in r studio and can't be able to install packages

Tags: r

package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3’ for modifying
Try removing ‘C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3/00LOCK’

I can't find 00LOCK folder in my PC.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what does `unlink("C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK", recursive = TRUE)` return?

Comment: By default, AppData is a hidden folder. [This link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) shows how to make hidden folders visible.